# MUI TextField inside Custom Tooltip loses focus when state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using MUI, and I've got a custom Tooltip around one TextField in a form. As soon as I type anything in that particular TextField, it loses focus. It updates the state of that value of my formData object to the one character I was able to type, so that value is only ever one character long.
The other TextFields in my form work as expected. If I replace the custom Tooltip with a standard one, that particular TextField works fine, too.
I've replicated the issue on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-lewin-kmi6u?file=/src/App.js:23-57). Here's the code I used there:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { TextField, Box } from "@mui/material";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Tooltip, { tooltipClasses } from "@mui/material/Tooltip";

export default function App() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    title: "",
    name: ""
  });

  const handleFormChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData((formData) => {
      return {
        ...formData,
        [name]: value
      };
    });
  };

  const CustomWidthTooltip = styled(({ className, ...props }) => (
    <Tooltip {...props} classes={{ popper: className }} />
  ))({
    [`& .${tooltipClasses.tooltip}`]: {
      maxWidth: 400
    }
  });

  return (
    <Box component="form" display="flex">
      // THIS ONE WORKS JUST FINE 
      <TextField
        onChange={handleFormChange}
        autoComplete="title"
        name="title"
        id="title"
        label="Title"
        required
      />
      // THIS ONE IS BROKEN
      <CustomWidthTooltip title="Foo">
        <TextField
          onChange={handleFormChange}
          autoComplete="name"
          name="name"
          id="name"
          label="Name"
          required
        />
      </CustomWidthTooltip>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Thanks for your help, folks! I appreciate you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're initializing `CustomWidthTooltip` inside the `App` component, which is causing the tooltip to reintialize on local state change.
Whenever the `name` is updated inside `formData` local state, the `TextField` inside the `CustomWidthTooltip` component is being recreated in the UI, causing the focus loss as a result.

You should move the `CustomWidthTooltip` out of the component `App`.

`Updated Code`

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import { TextField, Box } from "@mui/material";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Tooltip, { tooltipClasses } from "@mui/material/Tooltip";

const CustomWidthTooltip = styled(({ className, ...props }) => (
  <Tooltip {...props} classes={{ popper: className }} />
))({
  [`& .${tooltipClasses.tooltip}`]: {
    maxWidth: 400
  }
});

export default function App() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    title: "",
    name: ""
  });
  console.log("formData", formData);

  const handleFormChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    console.log({ name, value });
    setFormData((formData) => {
      return {
        ...formData,
        [name]: value
      };
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>With a custom tooltip, it's broken:</h3>
      <Box component="form" display="flex">
        <TextField
          onChange={handleFormChange}
          autoComplete="title"
          name="title"
          id="title"
          label="Title"
          required
        />
        <CustomWidthTooltip title="Custom Custom Custom Custom Custom Custom">
          <TextField
            onChange={handleFormChange}
            autoComplete="name"
            name="name"
            id="name"
            label="Name"
            required
          />
        </CustomWidthTooltip>
      </Box>
      <h3>With a standard tooltip, it works:</h3>
      <Box component="form" display="flex">
        <TextField
          onChange={handleFormChange}
          autoComplete="title"
          name="title"
          id="title"
          label="Title"
          required
        />
        <Tooltip title="Standard">
          <TextField
            onChange={handleFormChange}
            autoComplete="name"
            name="name"
            id="name"
            label="Name"
            required
          />
        </Tooltip>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit gallant-dijkstra-9fynn]

Comment: @alec this is the most correct answer tho, only use closure (and `useMemo`) if you have dependencies in your styled tooltip which in your case I can't see any. The other one is unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 2):

As Junaid mentioned, you are re-rendering the tooltip which is why it flashes.

I would personally use their solution and even move custom styled components into another file seeing as you will probably want to reuse them elsewhere.

Regardless, another alternative is the `useMemo` hook. This is a good opportunity for you to learn about how it can help.

You can leave your `CustomWidthTooltip` function where it is but just wrap it in `useMemo`:

```
import { useState, useMemo } from "react";

...

  const CustomWidthTooltip = useMemo(
    () =>
      styled(({ className, ...props }) => (
        <Tooltip {...props} classes={{ popper: className }} />
      ))({
        [`& .${tooltipClasses.tooltip}`]: {
          maxWidth: 400
        }
      }),
    [listOfDependencies]
  );

...
```

So this will calculate the styled component and store it to your variable, but it will not recreate it on subsequent renders. The array as the second parameter (`[listOfDependencies]`), is where you can add variables that it should watch. If there is any change to these variables, it will recompute `CustomWidthTooltip`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was actually just texting with another recent bootcamp grad about how I needed to learn useMemo. I appreciate this!